Is there a name for words that differ only in character case?
How can I to refer to the difference between Hello and hello? These words strings aren't exactly duplicates. What are they?
The context is I am writing software that needs to handle case-insensitivity. In that context hello and Hello are the same value. The word I am looking for should have nothing to do with the usage or position of hello vs Hello in a sentence.
Other examples include cat, Cat, CAT, cAt.
Edit #1
The phrase I am currently using to refer to this difference is "duplicate that differs only in letter case." I am looking for a word that means "duplicate that differs only in letter case."
Edit #2
Maybe I should call them strings instead of words. More examples include a1z38B and A1Z38b. When ignoring differences in letter case these two strings are the same. I am looking for a word that means "two or more strings that are identical when ignoring differences in letter case."

The word "Hello" is capitalized. The word "hello" isn't.

I doubt you'll do better than your 'strings that differ only in letter case'. Although perhaps there's a subject-specific term; this is probably better asked on ComputerScience.SE. A question asking for a term to describe pairs of elements such as aardVaRk as opposed to aardvark, or a1z38B as opposed to ... what? is unlikely to have an answer in common everyday use, though passwords (which are not a subset of English words) may encourage such.

The comparison is case sensitive. This is a question about software terminology not English language, and isn't specific to English; so should probably be moved.

Case folding is character-based and totally devoid of context. It is not used for display. So your question and the displayed example are actually two separate and unrelated  things. The displayed words are case transformations. But in the context of case folding, words don't exist.

Your "cat" examples are much better since "hello" has the same meaning regardless of case, but "cat" is an animal, "Cat" is a type of ethernet cable or maybe a nickname for Catherine or for a Caterpillar-brand earth mover, and "CAT" is an acronym for "computed axial tomography."
Since the meaning you're looking for goes beyond standard words and includes strings of meaningless characters, I doubt there's a single word that does everything you're hoping for. And as is often the case, the best solution is simply to spell out your meaning in as many words as it takes: character strings that are identical aside from capitalization.
As long as we're talking about meaningful words, like the "cat" examples, any variants that are determined by their capitalization are capitonyms. But beware, there are also homographs with different meanings but the same capitalization, like "dog" the animal and "dog" the verb.

I believe what you’re referring to here, @Andy Bonner, is what linguists call polysemy.

You have only a single word, which the rules of English-language syntax require that one either capitalize or not depending on its position in a sentence. They are no more distinct than the and The, or any other pair of written forms of any word that could conceivably appear in sentence-initial position.
The only exception is those pairs of common and proper nouns like bill (a printed statement of one’s debt) and Bill (the given name, or nickname for William). But these pairs are distinct words. For one thing, proper nouns are capitalized wherever in a sentence they appear. And so in the sentence

Bill Bill, since he’s the one who ran up all these charges

the first two words are different words, even though they are spelled identically and (here) capitalized identically, whereas in the sentence

Bills, bills, bills… my hand is cramping from writing all of these checks

we see three successive occurrences of the same word, once capitalized and then twice not.

I refer you to this part of my question: "The word I am looking for should have nothing to do with the usage or position of hello vs Hello in a sentence. Other examples include cat, Cat, CAT, cAt."

That’s as may be, but you are dealing with only a single word. Is there something that makes you think otherwise? Your OP reads, “These words aren’t exactly duplicates.” But they aren’t “words” they are written forms of the same single word.
